# Filtering imagesetthickness() to Specific line in PHP

Tags: php

The imagesetthickness() on the PHP will change the thickness of all lines on the image. Is there any way to select what line to be associated with this function? For Example in following image I would like to **ONLY** change the thickness of **GREEN** lines to 5.

```
<?php
 $image = ImageCreate(130, 170);
 $white = ImageColorAllocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
 $black = ImageColorAllocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
 $green = ImageColorAllocate($image, 82, 128, 8);

 ImageFill($image, 0, 0, $white);

 ImageSetThickness ($image , 5);

 ImageLine($image,60,40,60,100,$black);
 ImageLine($image,25,25,100,25,$green);

 ImagePng($image, "flag.png");
 ImageDestroy($image);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the thickness to the desired value before calling `imageline`.

```
<?php
 $image = ImageCreate(130, 170);
 $white = ImageColorAllocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
 $black = ImageColorAllocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
 $green = ImageColorAllocate($image, 82, 128, 8);

 ImageFill($image, 0, 0, $white);

 // set to 3 for the next call 
 ImageSetThickness ($image , 3);
 ImageLine($image,60,40,60,100,$black);

 // set to 5 for the next call
 ImageSetThickness ($image , 5);
 ImageLine($image,25,25,100,25,$green);

 // Set back to 3 for any future calls calls
 ImageSetThickness ($image , 3);

 ImagePng($image, "flag.png");
 ImageDestroy($image);
```

Comment: Thanks Drew010, Got it now